# "re-start" color range in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my scatterplot, I want to use two different shapes of points depending on "type" column, and range of fill colors depending on "probe" column, but I don't want the color range to be continuous, I want it to be re-started for every "type". In addition, I want to have it to be reflected in the legend. 
Here is what I have now:

```
require(data.table); require(ggplot2);

mydat <- fread(
"N,type,probe,value
1,A,Abc,2
1,A,Ade,4
1,B,Bfg,3
2,A,Ade,4
2,B,Bhi,3
3,B,Bfg,3
3,A,Axy,2
4,A,Ade,5
5,B,Bfg,2
5,A,Ade,1
6,A,Abc,1
6,B,Bhi,4
  ")

ggplot(mydat,
       aes(x=N, y=value, fill=probe, shape=type, label=probe)) +
  geom_point(size=4, alpha=0.8) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21,22)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name='probe') +
  geom_text(vjust=-0.8) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=24)))
```

[image: sample plot]

And here is what I want:
[image: desired view]

(in this example, "Abc" has the same color as "Bfg" etc, but in fact I don't care about exact correspondence of colors, I only need the scale to be re-started for each new "type")

Comment: I'm confused by your logic about what you want things to be colored by...but the path of least resistance will be do define a new column that accurately reflects the fills you want to use. Then just replace that with `probe`.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's indeed not clear from the text, but I don't know how to explain it better :/ Just look at the legend on both plots: as you see, originally it is one continuous scale for the whole range of "probe" values, while I want it to re-start for every "type". I already thought about making new column to define the category of color, but it's not obvious for me how to do this exactly.

Comment: Additionally, there's still the question on how to make the legend like in my second figure - but it's rather subject for separate question

Comment: Sorry - I don't get the connection between the colors and the type variable...if you're doing some sort of computation by type, `data.table` facilitates that with ease....something like `mydat[, newColumn := YourLogicHere(), by = type]`. If you can spell out in words what you want, i'd be happy to help write the code, I just don't grok the image at all...sorry.

Comment: yes, for the moment I found the following solution: `mydat[, newCol:=match(probe, unique(probe)), by=type]`, then convert it to discrete scale by `mydat[, newCol:=factor(newCol)];` - this re-starts color scale as desired (although for some reason palette is now different, but I don't really care), but the legend is now screwed...

Comment: ggplot2 uses different default color palettes for categorical (factor) and numerical data. The legend stuff will likely be a bit tricky, but here's a good resource for you to start with; http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Comment: yep, cookbook-r is very useful resource which I often go by. I could not find the solution for this specific task though... I will try to go through it again. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather non-standard usage of variable mapping, so you may want to rethink the design of your plot (I'm with @Chase here). But if that's really what you want, then you'll have to precompute the palette manually, like so. I'm assuming the alphabetical order of `type` variable, you'll need additional ordering if that's not the case.

```
library(scales)
pal <- numeric(0)
for (tp in unique(mydat$type))
{
  n <- length(unique(subset(mydat, type == tp)$probe))
  pal <- c(pal, hue_pal()(n))
}

ggplot(mydat,
       aes(x=N, y=value, fill=probe, shape=type, label=probe)) +
  geom_point(size=4, alpha=0.8) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(21, 22)) +
  scale_fill_manual(name='probe', values = pal) +
  geom_text(vjust=-0.8) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=24)))
```

[image]

Edit: for consistent colors, use e.g. the following adjustment

```
pal <- numeric(0)
max_pal <- 5
for (tp in unique(mydat$type))
{
  n <- length(unique(subset(mydat, type == tp)$probe))
  pal <- c(pal, hue_pal()(max_pal)[1:n])
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I like how the palette is calculated here, without creating new column. The task of making "combined" legend (as in my second figure) remains actual, but I will probably make it a separate question.